# How to scrape a webpage with dynamic script using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking for a better way to scrape the latest exchange rate from https://www.remitly.com/us/en/india

With the current code below I get 16 instances of 'script' and then going through each one of them and looking if they contain the exchange rate is one way to do it. Is there a better way?

The issue here is that I cannot use additional attributes with `soup.find_all()`. Also the array elements are too large.

```
# get current exchange rate

import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import parser
from pprint import pprint

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.remitly.com/us/en/india')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

#js_test = soup.findAll('td', class_='f1smo2ix')
cost = soup.find_all('script')

print(cost)
print(len(cost))
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `BeautifulSoup`, you can use `.find_next_sibling(text=True)` to get the rate:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.remitly.com/us/en/india'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('sup:contains("₹")').find_next_sibling(text=True) )
```

Prints:

```
75.55
```

Answer (score 1):

I think best way to achieve is using [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). You use a query like `//sup[text() = '₹']` to locate `<sup>`elements that have the text content `₹`. After you located it, get the text in parent. Here is a working sample for your situation:

```py
import urllib.request
from lxml import etree

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.remitly.com/us/en/india')
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)

rate_tree = tree.xpath("//sup[text() = '₹']")[0].getparent()
etree.strip_elements(rate_tree, 'sup', with_tail=False)
rate = rate_tree.text

print(rate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up scraping `<script> \__REMITLY_LANDING_PAGE_CONTEXT__ = { \** *JSON OBJECT HERE* ** } </script>`

The JSON object provided several additional details that is easy to access. Below is the code:

```
# get current exchange rate

import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.remitly.com/us/en/india'

source = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

script = soup.find('script', text=re.compile('__REMITLY_LANDING_PAGE_CONTEXT__'))

nextsc = script.next.strip('__REMITLY_LANDING_PAGE_CONTEXT__ = ')

json_obj = json.loads(nextsc)

economy = json_obj['context']['forex']['current']['economy']['everyday']
print("Economy rate 1 USD is " + economy + " INR.")

express = json_obj['context']['forex']['current']['express']['everyday']
print("Express rate 1 USD is " + express + " INR.")

special = json_obj['context']['forex']['current']['express']['effective']
print("Special rate for first time senders 1 USD is " + special + " INR.")
```

Thanks to @andrej-kesely and @dorukerenaktas for their answers which let me ponder more on this topic.